# Unable to create a folder in internal storage on android 6.0+

Tags: java, android, path, storage, internal-storage

I first tryed to create a folder in the external directory with

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml, i had those 2 lines so everything should be allright.

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

but now i know that you have to ask the user every time they install the app for permission and if he won't give me the permission, my app would not work.

So i know, that you dont need a permission for writing in the internal storage.
So i used the command

```
getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()
```

to read / write to the storage.
But it wont worked on devices with Android 6.0 or higher.
My code for creating the file is

```
String mainPath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "//testFile/";
    File dir = new File(mainPath);

    if(!dir.exists())
    {
        dir.mkdir();

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else { }
```

everytime when i run the App, i get into the else{ } part and i have no idea why.
It would be nice if you could help me.

Thank You!

Comment: `My code for creating the file is`. That does not create a file but a directory.

Comment: `i get into the else{ } part and i have no idea why. ` Well then the directory exists already.

Comment: sorry i wrote it wrong... everytime i run the app, !dir.exists() is true. In my App, this Code is repeated several times to check if there is a directory or no but each time i go into the if part and it should create the directory but instead the other code is executed while the file isn't created

Comment: `while the file isn't created –` ??????

Comment: Further there is no other code. What do you mean? Is it that difficult to explain what happens?

Comment: `dir.mkdir();`. You should check the return value of mkdir() and handle accordingly.

Comment: it returnes false :/

Comment: Then first adapt the code. We like to see how you handle this properly.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the file exists. Create the file if it doesn't exist and then start your activity.

```
if(!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdir();
}

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: sorry i wrote it wrong... everytime i run the app, !dir.exists() is true.
In my App, this Code is repeated several times to check if there is a directory or no but each time i go into the if part and it should create the directory but instead the other code is executed while the file isn't created

Answer (score 0):

Creating a File object doesn't make the directory.  To do that, you need to call `dir.mkdirs()`.

Also, the right way to get the File is `File dir = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir, "testFile");`  That way you don't need to assume the separator or do string manipulation

Comment: But it worked on my Android 5.0 Phone but not on a 8.0 Phone :/